# Why does stroke cause insomnia?

Tags: insomnia, stroke

As per this article,
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12499712
insomnia is a common complaint after ischemic stroke.
Why does ischemic stroke leads to insomnia ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, stroke may be associated with insomnia, not because of the brain tissue damage, but because of how it affects someone's life.

[Insomnia is a likely long-term side effect of stroke, study finds (ScienceDaily, 2018)](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/05/180530113136.htm):

> Importantly researchers found that although sleep efficiency was
>   reduced in patients, total sleep time between the groups was similar,
>   suggesting that *lesions in the brains' centres for sleep-wake
>   regulation are unlikely to cause the insomnia.* Rather researchers
>   believe that sleep problems experienced by stroke patients are due to
>   a number of contributory factors, such as **greater psychological
>   strain, pain and discomfort as well as reduced levels of physical
>   activity.**

The article [What happens to sleep after a stroke? (Medscape)](https://www.medscape.org/viewarticle/508962) describes how different stroke locations can result in different types of insomnia:

> - A pontine stroke may be expected to affect REM sleep.
> - Particular lesion sites have been reported to cause narcolepsy, destruction of normal circadian sleep/wake patterns, and regional loss.
>     of sleep spindles, but also loss of dream life, a peculiar bed-prone
>     behavioral stereotypy, and visual hallucinations.
> - Subcortical strokes affecting basal ganglia may be more associated with excessive daytime sleepiness.
> - Immediately after a hemispheric stroke, REM sleep abnormalities are more common. Over a period of weeks after a hemispheric stroke, it is
>     common to observe reduction in total sleep time, sleep efficiency, and
>     sleep stages.
> - In one study of hemispheric strokes, one third of stroke patients slept more.

Comment: Interesting information, but it doesn't answer the question, which is why?

Comment: This is exactly what I answered. If you don't think so, you may want to say, what do you think is missing.

Comment: Psychological strain, pain and discomfort, and reduced levels of activity are features of many illnesses that aren't known to cause insomnia. I'm not criticizing your answer. I'm simply saying I think the answer is probably "we don't know why."

Comment: If you ask me, all those things can very well cause insomnia, regardless of the cause, including stroke. Anyway, I'm not sure when did you see my answer; it has two parts - the second part shows that they actually found few locations that can explain why exactly a certain damage causes insomnia. My point is that stroke can be associated with insomnia due to 1) patients' changed life or 2) directly due to brain damage.